# Android Design Support Library: NavigationView source code

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I have searched several hours over the past few days for the complete source code of Android's design support library. I have found source code mirrored from the official Google repository:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/design

However, I have yet to find the source code for android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. The jar file for the library contains a NavigationView.class, but has no source attached.

How should I find the source of this class? Is the code possibly not released to the public?

Comment: "How should I find the source of this class" Why do you need the source? In intellij, simply click on the class and it will show you the source or decompile it for you.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I need the source because I would like to learn more about how it works; I would like to create a similar but more versatile class.

Comment: Read the docs and use Intellij.

Answer (score 5):

If you download the Android 6.0 source code from your SDK Manager, you will find the source for `NavigationView` in:

```
$ANDROID_SDK/sources/android-23/android/support/design/widget
```

where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have installed the Android SDK.

My guess is that this matches the 23.0.0 version of the Design Support library. I do not know if patches (e.g., 23.0.1) will have their source show up here or not. And, for all I know, what is here in the source code is older than 23.0.0. Google's packaging of source code for the support libraries could use some love.

Comment: I had found this information elsewhere, but as you say the code is definitely outdated. Actually the other support libraries are fine, the sources are pulled down with the gradle dependency AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they've since made this available via Github.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/39adac1bf95746faf784fba67b5545ae2b66374b/design/src/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.java

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.java

I use a plugin for chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin?hl=en that allows search for sdk documentation and viewing source code as well.